# Create objective-c class instance by name?

Tags: objective-c, reflection

Is it possible to create an instance of a class by name? Something like:

```
NSString* className = @"Car";
id* p = [Magic createClassByName:className];
[p turnOnEngine];
```

I don't know if this is possible in objective-c but seems like it would be,

Answer (score 220, accepted):

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];
```

Comment: This won't cause any leaks?

Answer (score 39):

`NSClassFromString()` runs the risk of mistyping the class name or otherwise using a class that doesn't exist. You won't find out until runtime if you make that error. Instead, if you use the built-in objective-c type of `Class` to create a variable, then the compiler will verify that the class exists.

For example, in your `.h`:

```
@property Class NameOfClass;
```

and then in your `.m`:

```
id object = [[NameOfClass alloc] init];
```

If you mistyped the class name or if it doesn't exist, you'll get an error at compile time. Also I think this is cleaner code.

Comment: there you go, buddy. Not entirely sure it's the best answer, as it requires two lines and is less dynamic, but upvoted all the same

Comment: I suppose you could say that it's less dynamic because I used a symbol instead of a string. However, if you know the class that you want when you are writing the code, then it's preferable to use the symbol so as to avoid possible typos.

Comment: @sbwoodside: How can this work? I tried it and I got "Undefined symbols for architecture" from the linker.

Comment: Change it to [[[self class] alloc] init]; You don't need anything else.

Comment: The OP's use-case is more than legit - it is the base for any serialization of object hierarchy to file/memory-block/plist/whatever. Many times you DO NOT KNOW in advance which classes you'll need to instantiate. My use-case is the tedious need to "register" gazillion "NSValueTransformer"s and instead of duplicating  [NSValueTransformer setValueTransformer:MyTransformerA alloc] init] forName:@"MyTransformerA"]; 40 times - I just scan an NSArray of transformer names - and create/register them from string.

Comment: I never said that creating from a string is not legit. However, note that the OP did say "create by name" not "create by string".

Answer (score 8):

If you are working with Objective-C without the `NeXTstep` (`OS X`, `iOS`, `GNUstep` etc) system  or you just think this method is cleaner, then you could utilize the [Objective-C language runtime library's API](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).  Under `Objective-C 2.0`:

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
//Declaration in the above named file
id objc_getClass(const char* name);
//Usage
id c = objc_getClass("Object");
[ [ c alloc ] free ];
```

Under the Objective-C (1.0 or unnamed version) you would utilize the following:

```
#import <objc/objc-api.h>
//Declaration within the above named file
Class objc_get_class( const char* name);
//Usage
Class cls = objc_get_class( "Test" );
id obj = class_create_instance( cls );
[ obj free ];
```

I haven't tested the `1.0` version, however I have used the `2.0` function in code that is now in production.  I personally believe utilizing the `2.0` function is cleaner if available than the NS function as it consumes less space: `the length of the name in bytes + 1 ( null terminator )` for the 2.0 API versus `the sum of two pointers (isa, cstring)`, a `size_t length (cstring_length)`, and the `length of the string in bytes + 1` for the `NeXTSTEP` API.

Answer (score 2):

```
@interface Magic : NSObject
+ (id)createInstanceOfClass:(Class)classe;
@end

@implementation Magic

+ (id)createInstanceOfClass:(Class)classe
{
    return [[classe alloc] init];
}

@end
```

Then to use it:

```
Car *car = [Magic createInstanceOfClass:[Car class]];
[car engineTurnOn];
```