# allocing an object based on a string name

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way in objective-c/Cocoa to alloc an object when the class name isn't know until run-time.  I seem to remember something about this a while ago, but can't find anything on it now.

Something like:

```
[[@"MyClass" alloc] init];
```

I seem to recall a function that would return some kind of class id based on a string that can then be used to alloc the object.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create objective-c class instance by name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"MyClass") alloc] init];
```