# Creating an object, strange question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring, cocos2d-iphone, nested

I have a class "Projectiles", and I want to create an object with it.
To minimise code, I want to specify the object from a string, it would clean up thins alot.

Example:
I have the string,

```
tempenemy.atktype = @"homing_fireball";
```

Now i want to create an object with the same name from Projectiles class:

```
Projectiles *tempenemy.atktype;
```

Is this possible? So the final result would be an object from Projectiles class called homing_fireball..?

Thanks!!

Comment: Is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt that this is possible. But I'm not an expert for the inner core of objective-c.

I would suggest you to store your Projectile in a NSMutableDictionary. You could store the object with a key of @"homing_fireball". And then you can reference it with something like

```
Projectile *someProjectile = [myProjectiles objectForKey:tempenemy.atktype];
```

Answer (score 0):

If i am getting what you mean, you are trying to init a projectiles object with a atktype as its member? You call in main..

```
Projectiles* tempProjectiles = [[Projectiles alloc]initWithType:@"homing_fireball"];
```

Your projectiles.h

```
// blah blah blah
{
NSString* atktype;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain)NSString* atktype;
 -(id)initWithType:(NSString*)type;
```

Your projectiles.m

```
@synthesize atktype;
-(id)initWithType:(NSString*)type
{
      self = [super init];
         if(self)
          {
             atktype = type;
          }
     return self;
}
```