# Generate classes dynamically

Tags: objective-c, class, dynamic

Is it possible to create classes dynamically in Objective-C?

I want to do something like this, but dynamically:

```
Mission *mission = [[Mission alloc]init];
        mission.Id = [modelObject Id];
        mission.EntityState = [modelObject EntityState];
        mission.Description = [modelObject Description];
```

So I tried this

```
id clonedobject = [[[modelObject class] alloc]init];
for (NSString *key in dic) 
    {
        [[clonedobject valueForKey:[dic objectForKey:key]] addObject:[modelObject valueForKey:[dic objectForKey:key]]];
    }
```

But with this code, I cannot reach for example the id with clonedobject.Id. It says "Property ID not found on object of type id.

Is there a way to do something like this?

```
[modelObject class] *clonedobject = [[[modelObject class] alloc]init]
```

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name

Answer (score 6, accepted):

please refer to the given link ..
[Creating class at runtime](http://cocoawithlove.com/2010/01/what-is-meta-class-in-objective-c.html)

Comment: +1 for the link. But you should consider adding the essence of that article over here. (Just for a quick reference)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to register classes at runtime, but this is not what you're looking for.

Even if you could add classes at *runtime*, it would not help you with the *compile-time* type of the variable. i.e. You would still not know the type at *compile-time*, and thus you still cannot use properties using dot notation like `clonedobject.id`.

How do you know that this object has a property called `id`? It seems like you already know what type it is.