# Instantiate Class object by its name

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, nsstring

I would like to instantiate a class object by using its unique class name. First I create a NSString object like this

```
for (i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    NSString *abc = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"item%i",i];
```

How can I create a class object by using the above NSString object:

```
myClass *abc;
```

Comment: id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];

Comment: You could add your objects in an NSDictionary with keys the strings you create in the loop.

Comment: can you tell me how am i going to do that?? actually i am new

Comment: @user2966615 as you are new there may be a chance that you are attending wrong approach please clear the problem first, Why you want this ?

Comment: If I did understand your question correctly, then the answer is Yes! You can create a class that is a subclass of NSString. The interface would be something like: `@interface yourClass : NSString`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Create objective-c class instance by name?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name)

Answer (score 0):

To get class from string:

```
Class cl = NSClassFromString(@"YourClass");
```

To get class from existing variable:

```
Class cl = [obj class];
```

To create an object:

```
YourClass *myClass = (YourClass *)[cl new];
```