# How to instantiate an object from a stored Class?

Tags: objective-c, class, instantiation

I have an function which gives me back a Class:

```
- (Class)classForMyType:(NSString *)myType;
```

This class is given back like this:

```
return [MyFirstClass class];
```

In the code, where I call this function, I can store the Class like this:

```
Class myClass = [self classForMyType:@"foo"];
```

How can I instantiate a variable in the type of `myClass`? I want something like `myClass *foo = [[myClass alloc] init]`, but this does not work.

Comment: if i understand your question right here it is: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name

Comment: You are right, I can instantiate the object by `id foo = [[myClass alloc] init];`, but this way the pointer won't have the proper class. Is it maybe possible to have a class pointer too?

Comment: with [[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init]; you can instantiate with name. then if you want you can parse this class to your own class as i know

Comment: The problem is the same, I can use this with `id` only, am I right?

Comment: `WhateverClassIHad* foo = (WhateverClassIHad*) [[myClass alloc] init];`.  If you don't know `WhateverClassIHad` (or a suitable interface name) then you don't care anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can instantiate it like this if you're using a string.

```
id object = [[NSClassFromString(@"NameofClass") alloc] init];
```

Based on your code it looks like you're not type-casting your class. Either instantiate it like this with an id

```
id foo = [[myClass alloc] init]
```

Or explicitly type-cast like this (notice MyClass is not your instance variable but your actual class name):

```
MyClass *foo = [[myClass alloc] init]
```

Comment: If I would know the exact class name at that point, I would not have created a function for giving it back :)

Comment: lol yeah thats what I figured, but I put it in just in case. I don't think its possible to do what you want. I think the best you can do is instantiate it as its parent class if you know that for sure, but other than that I don't think you can do it without an id but I'll keep looking!

Comment: The cast on the right side of the assignment does nothing. You never need to cast an expression of type `id` to another object type.

Comment: It would be `id` not `id *`

Comment: My b guys - I corrected both mistakes. the id * was a typo and you're right about the right type-cast not doing anything. I've updated my answer.