# how to i access the property of object i have property name in string format in ios?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have name of class in string Format.
And i want to make Object of that class.
As well as i have the name of data member in string.

How to make object of that class ?
How to access property of that class ?

Comment: with Class name u can create instance . instance.str;

Comment: Check accepted answer of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1174093/create-objective-c-class-instance-by-name) question.

Answer (score 1):

To create an instance of a class based on the class name:

```
Class MyClass = NSClassFromString(@"Person");
id someObj = [[MyClass alloc] init];
```

To access a property of an object by name (key):

```
NSString *firstName = [someObj valueForKey:@"firstName"];
```

You can also modify a property of an object by name (key):

```
[someObj setValue:@"Freddy" forKey:@"firstName];
```