# How can I create an instance of Objective C instance by name in KMM?

Tags: ios, objective-c, kotlin-multiplatform

I want to create an Objective C class instance, input is class string, in KMM with Kotlin, is this possible?

```
fun createObject(className: String): Any? {
    if (className == "MyCustomClass") {
        // create a instance of MyCustomClass and return
    }
//    return null
}
```

Comment: OK, I have edit the example code to explain my goal

Answer (score 0):

This is [how](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1174127/3585796) you can do it in ObjC:

```objectivec
[[NSClassFromString(className) alloc] init];
```

I'm not sure if you can do it from Swift, but Kotlin doesn't have such an option according to [this discussion](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-native/issues/3247).

So the only option I can think of that might work is to create ObjC files that implement this functionality, and then add them to your project using [`cinterops`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/multiplatform-dsl-reference.html#cinterops).

Comment: func NSClassFromString(_ aClassName: String) -> AnyClass? also available in swift

Comment: @Dewerro it's available, but how are you going to create an object instance from `AnyClass`?